# how do I put a button to select the data of a registration and update this code in Vue.js? (CLOSED)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I made a "table" where I register this data, it is a crud that saves in memory and I already made the option to save and delete, I now need to update/edit, I would like to make a button that selects the registration and the data of it appears for editing, basically it's a simple crud system in Vue.js. I've done it to save and to delete, now I need the rest.

```
<body>

<div id="app">

    <div class="container">

        <h1>Formulário de Cadastro v.Vue</h1>

        <form class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" v-model="form.name" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Idade:</label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Idade" v-model="form.age" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Telefone:</label>
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Telefone" v-model="form.phone" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Gênero:</label>
                <select class="form-select form-control" v-model="form.gender">
                    <option>Masculino</option>
                    <option>Feminino</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Data de Cadastro:</label>
                <input type="date" v-model="form.registerdate" class="form-control">
            </div>

        </form>
        <br />
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Salvar" v-on:click="save" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" />
            <input type="button" value="Atualizar" v-on:click="update" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" v-if="contacts.length > 0">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Idade</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Gênero</th>
                    <th>Data de Cadastro</th>
                    <th>Opções</th>
                </tr>

                <tr v-for="contact in contacts">
                    <td>{{contact.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.registerdate}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Excluir" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                            v-on:click="remove(contact.id)" />
                        <input type="button" value="Selecionar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                            v-on:click="select(contact.id)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <div :class="classAlert" role="alert" v-if="showMessage">
                    {{messageAlert}}
                </div>

            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            classAlert: '',
            messageAlert: '',
            showMessage: false,
            inputName: '',
            currentCount: 0,
            currentId: 1,
            form: {
                name: '',
                age: 0,
                phone: '',
                gender: '',
                registerdate: ''
            },
            contacts: []
        },
        methods: {
            incrementCount: function () {
                this.currentCount++;
            },

            save: function () {
                var _this = this;
                // if (this.selectContact === null) {

                // }
                // else {

                // }

                this.contacts.push({
                    id: this.currentId++,
                    name: this.form.name,
                    age: this.form.age,
                    phone: this.form.phone,
                    gender: this.form.gender,
                    registerdate: this.form.registerdate
                });

                this.classAlert = 'alert alert-success';
                this.messageAlert = "Salvo Com sucesso";
                this.showMessage = true;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    _this.showMessage = false
                }, 3000);

            },
            remove: function (id) {
                var _this = this;

                this.contacts = this.contacts.filter(p => p.id != id);

                this.classAlert = 'alert alert-danger'
                this.messageAlert = "Excluido Com sucesso";
                this.showMessage = true;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    _this.showMessage = false
                }, 3000);
            },

            select: function (id) {

                var _this = this;

                const contact = this.contacts.filter(contact => contact.id === id);

                this.form.name = contact[0].name;
                this.form.age = contact[0].age;
                this.form.phone = contact[0].phone;
                this.form.gender = contact[0].gender;
                this.form.registerdate = contact[0].registerdate;
            },
            update: function () {
                var _this = this;
                const l_contactUpdate = this.contacts.filter(l_contactUpdate => l_contactUpdate.name === name);

                this.form.name = form.name;
            }

            // update/edit method??
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want us to write the update/edit functionality ? What did you tried to achieve these operations ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I tried to update the entries in this table, you need to put everything on the same page but I don't know how I can do it. I need to put edit/update function

Comment: I made a button where you select the data and display it on the form

Comment: On update method, you have to just get the form elements v-model value. So that you can send those in an update API call

Comment: i made > https://github.com/lucasmenchon/simple_crud_vue